# React Router - path with regular expression and parameter not equal to a string

Tags: reactjs, regex, react-router

I'm trying to figure out what the path could be if there are condition:

should match:

```
/app/project/37gfhdjf87
```

should not match:

```
/app/project/item
```

So, the idea is to create a path that would match a route only if its id not equal 'item'. I tried this one but it's not working:

```
/app/project/:id(^(?!item$))
```

I have the exception "Invalid regular expression: /^/app/project/((?:[^/]+?))(^((?:?!item$)))(?:/(?=$))?(?=/|$)/: Nothing to repeat"

Upd. I can't control the order of routes that is why I need to distinguish them.

Comment: Do you have separate `<Route>` for `/app/project/item`?

Comment: @KenBekov Yes, I have the separate route, some of them are generated programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a route that matches *exactly* "/app/project/item" and redirect back to a home route, or render null, and after have a route to match "/app/project/:id".

Example

```
<Router>
  ...
  <Switch>
    ...
    <Redirect from="/app/project/item" to="/" exact />
    <Route path="/app/project/:id" component={Page} />
    ...
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-router-path-with-regular-expression-and-parameter-not-equal-to-a-string]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't control the order of routes. That is why I want a more flexible solution.

Comment: @mimic Curious, why can't you control the order of the routes in the router?

Comment: Because many of them are generated programmatically.

Comment: @mimic Many of them, but not all of them? The route/redirect to match "/app/project/item" doesn't need to be declared *immediately* before the route matching "/app/project/:id", it just needs to be able to match before the route matching gets to "/app/project/:id". Does this make sense? I'm not trying to convince you to accept my answer, BTW, I think aziz's is better (if it works), but just pointing out that you do have control over route order.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. Unfortunately, the routes I'm considering here, both are generated programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if the path is like what you want or not , else you Redirect to another path :

```
<Route exact path="/app/project/:id" component={(props)=>{  
     return isTruePath(props.match.url) ?<ProjectComponent {...props}/> : <Redirect to="/"/>
}} />
```

and **isTruePath** :

```
\*
* this will return false :id === item
* true otherwise
*
*\
const isTruePath = (str)=> {
    let re = /^(\/app\/project\/)(?!item)/;
    return re.test(str);
}
```

explain regex :

- ^ : Match the beginning of string
- (/app/project/) : same as /app/project/
- (?!item) : Not followed by 'item' string

this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tu9uzq?file=src/App.js)